# Set a global parameters in Asp.Net MVC 3/4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm creating a MVC application with a CRUD. In the list view I have the PagedList helper. I set the pageSize variable in the code: pageSize= 5, so the list only show 5 files and allow go to the previous and next pages.
In the other side, I want to create an option called "Parameters" where the user can define yourself the "pageSize" value.
I'm confused about how to do it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a Profile provider

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1327/profile-provider-in-aspnet-mvc/

Or create a bespoke UserSettings table to store the setting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write pagesize that user choose in session variable and read it from it when you need:

To write to session you should call:

```
Session["pagesize"]=pagesize;
```

To read from session you can use:

```
var pagesize = (int)Session["pagesize"];
```

You should check that this value is in session before cast to avoid null reference exception.

Session variable can be used when you want keep it only during working period of user. If you want save it for long period, you should save it into database or in file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Sql Sever`, then do a simple table

```
Create Table UserProfile (
  UserId Int Not null, 
  ProfileName Varchar(50) Not null
  Value Varchar(50) Not Null
  foreign key (UserId) references [UsersTable] (UserId)
)
```

You can save and retrieve `PageSize or any other profile` from this table.

Answer (score 0):

What's common among modern web applications is a *page size* `<select />` list:

[image]

What you want to do next is **remember the user's choice in a cookie**. The user experience (UX) is much better than the *profile approach* for 2 reasons:

1. both registered and **anonymous users** can select a page size
2. it is not necessary to navigate to a setting or profile page to select the page size

There are scenarios that call for a profile page but definitely not this one.